# Using array to change colours

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

hi I'm trying to use an array to change colors. I want to Make a function called ChangeColor(num) with an argument for numbers and Use the function to change the color of the box so when the button is clicked on, it calls on the function and sends the correct number so that "box.style.backgroundColor = arrName[num];" Heres what i got so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    #box {
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
        background-color:black;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="group">
        <button id="blue">Blue</button>
        <button id="red">Red</button>
        <button id="green">Green</button>
    </div>

    <div id="box"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var colors = ["blue","red","green"];
        var blue = document.getElementById("blue");
        var red = document.getElementById("red");
        var green = document.getElementById("green");
        var box = document.getElementById("box");

        var numclicks = 0;

        blue.addEventListener("click", function() {
            if(numclicks == 0) {
                box.style.backgroundColor = colors[0];   
            }
        });

        red.addEventListener("click", function() {
            if(numclicks == 0) {
                box.style.backgroundColor = colors[1];   
            }
        });

        green.addEventListener("click", function() {    
            if(numclicks == 0) {
                box.style.backgroundColor = colors[2];   
            }
        });        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So far is not too far, you don't even have the function declared. Have you tried creating the function? In that case, what exact problem do you have creating the function? We can help you with your homework but you have to put some effort.

Comment: lol i agree. sorry  i didn't put much effort. I edited the code, is this an ideal way to do it ?

Comment: What *exactly* is the problem you are having?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply attach an event listener to the buttons within `#group` and set the `background-color` of the `#box` the id of the clicked button:

```js
var box = document.querySelector('#box');

document
  .querySelectorAll('#group button')
  .forEach(function (el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', function () {
      box.style.backgroundColor = el.id;
    });
});
```

```css
#box {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:black;
}
```

```html
<div id="group">
  <button id="blue">Blue</button>
  <button id="red">Red</button>
  <button id="green">Green</button>
</div>

<div id="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

standard function

```
const colors = ["blue","red","green"];
const defaultColor = "white"; // if you want for kill errors

function changeColor(num){
    document.querySelector("#box").style.backgroundColor = colors[num]||defaultColor
}
```

then you can added onclick events to buttons like this

```
<div id="group">
    <button onclick="changeColor(0)" id="blue">Blue</button>
    <button onclick="changeColor(1)" id="red">Red</button>
    <button onclick="changeColor(0)" id="green">Green</button>
</div>
```

or with attributes like (but keep buttons elements depend to same order of array colors names)
**html**

```
<div id="group">
    <button number="0" id="blue">Blue</button>
    <button number="1" id="red">Red</button>
    <button number="2" id="green">Green</button>
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
document.querySelectorAll("#group button").forEach((button)=>{
    button.addEventListener('click', function () {
        changeColor(button.getAttr("number"));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions use practices that are currently considered better. Here is a solution that includes the unnecessary array.

```js
function changeColor(num) {
    var colors = ['blue', 'red', 'green'];

    document.getElementById('box').style.backgroundColor = colors[num];
}
```

```css
#box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="group">
    <button id="blue" onclick="changeColor(0)">Blue</button>
    <button id="red" onclick="changeColor(1)">Red</button>
    <button id="green" onclick="changeColor(2)">Green</button>
</div>

<div id="box"></div>
```